# Material angular infinite scroll not showing in drop down menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've got the following.

```
var vm = this;
vm.infiniteItems = {
  numLoaded_: 0,
  toLoad_: 0,
  items: [],

  // Required.
  getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
    if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
      this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
      return null;
    }
    return this.items[index];
  },

  // Required.
  getLength: function() {
    return this.numLoaded_ + 5;
  },

  fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {
    if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
      this.toLoad_ += 5;
      WafersFactory.get().success(angular.bind(this, function(obj) {
        this.items = this.items.concat(obj.success);
        console.log(this.items);
        this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
      }));
    }
  }
};

$scope.mdSelectOnOpen = function() {
  return $timeout(function() {
    $scope.$broadcast("$md-resize");
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  }, 100);
}
```

And HTML like this:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-controller="WafersCtrl as ctrl" flex-gt-sm>
  <label>Wafer</label>
  <md-select ng-model="ctrl.data.wafer_id" placeholder="Wafer" md-on-open="mdSelectOnOpen()">
    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
      <md-option md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.infiniteItems" md-on-demand class="repeated-item" ng-value="item.id" flex>{{item.serial_number}}</md-option>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
    <div ng-hide="ctrl.infiniteItems.length">No items found</div>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

The thing is nothing is showing up.

[image]

Did some research, related issue was mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10868)

I was using `angularjs 1.4.7` updated this to `1.5.7` with latest `angular-material` and still experiencing this same issue. I also tried down-grading the material version to `1.0.0-rc1`. Nothing seems to work. That `console.log` you're seeing spits out the following in my console.

[image]

Comment: Can't it be a problem because of the value of this on line `this.items = this.items.concat.....` ?

Comment: @Zyigh What kind of a problem? Please elaborate..

Comment: Well I was thinking maybe `this` refers to any element which cannot be accessed by the front end to display the list. I don't know how to be more precise as I'm really not an expert of JavaScript, and `this` can have so many different values... Maybe not a good practice but what about attaching items to `vm` so you'd have to loop over `ctrl.items` ?

Comment: @Zyigh Thanks for your time! The JS code above is heavily based on google docs https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat   Other than that, not sure what else to do.

Comment: What happen if you console.log `this` instead of `this.items` ? This is just a guess and I hope I'm not making you lose your time

Comment: @Zyigh It spits out the array.